# Print Object attributes after creation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to rails and I want to jut print in the console the name of the lastly created record of `Document`. For this I am using in the model file, after? create callback.

Anyway I can not get the name displayed in the console after I run a procedure of creation. How can this be done to be able to display the name of the lastly created record of type `Document`?

```
 class Document < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :storage

  after_create :my_function

  def my_function
    puts Document.name
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Document` you reference the class, not the newly created instance. Instead do:

```
  def my_function
    puts name
  end
```

To understand it better, you can also call:

```
  def my_function
    puts self.name
  end
```

so that you see that you're calling this `name` method on the current instance. It's not idiomatic though.

Comment: but after_create don't fire at all. Even if I try to print just a sting it don't get printed. Maybe I should use another callback provided by rails?

Comment: Are you sure that the document is persisted? `after_create` should be called after regular creation of a document. Btw how do you create the document? What is the result of this call?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the last created record of Document,

you should do

```
puts Document.last.name
```

Basically when you call 'Document.name', you're calling #name, an instance method, on the class Document. You need to call it on an instance, aka a record.

If you want to print out the name of the CURRENT document record that you're inside and accessing

```
 puts self.name
```

All of this is assuming that you have a name attribute on your Document model.